# Algorithm for finding the minimum index in array with value exceeding x

Tags: arrays, binary-search

Given a set $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_k\}$, find the minimum index $j$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^j s_i \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i = 1}^k s_i$.

I was reading in a paper about an algorithm for this problem that is described as follows:

> The idea is to construct an array of size $k$, whose $j$th position contains $\sum_{i = 1}^j s_i$. Then one can find the appropriate index $j$ in $O(\log(\min\{j, k - j\}))$ time by using a form of binary search simultaneously from both ends of the array.

Can someone explain how the binary search might work? I know that constructing the array still takes $O(k)$, but I want to use this in an algorithm where the array would be computed just once and used with recursive calls to this algorithm.

Comment: If the $s_i$ are unconstrained, the prefix sum has no reason to be monotonic and binary search seems unusable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, they are all positive, yes i should have specified this

Comment: Consider adding that as an update to your post.

Comment: Could you give a full citation to the paper, please? There may well be relevant information in it that you've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $s_i$ positive (which wasn't said in the OP), the prefix sum of $s_i$ forms a monotonic sequence.

You can start a simultaneous exponential search from both ends, followed by a standard binary search when the half sum has been crossed. The left exponential search takes $O(\log(j))$ and the right one $O(\log(k-j))$. As they are performed simultaneously, the fastest "wins".

Comment: Can you explain or provide references explaining what is a double exponential search? I looked it up and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Just lookup exponential search and infer what double can mean (renamed *simultaneous* since).

Comment: I mostly get the idea, but for the right exponential search how should I initialize the bound? I think i should initialize to the smallest power of 2 that is larger than the size of $S$, but that means i need to be able to do this in O(log(min{j,k−j}))  time, right?

Comment: @SimonZhu: no, use indexes $k+1-j$ instead of $j$.